# RadTimePicker current culture not work

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

I have used RadTimePicker and set system culture but it is not working

```
<telerik:RadTimePicker Width="80" Culture="{x:Static glob:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}"/>
```

but it is not get system culture. I am trying to set this culture in xaml not backend and as well as without using convertor.

Comment: As i tested, it works and without Culture changing.

Comment: Try targeting the application to .NET 4.5.2 or older and see if that works for you. If it does, then you are likely hitting a bug that has been introduced in .NET 4.6 and only affects applications that are explicitly targeted at .NET 4.6 or later. If this suggestion doesn't help, then perhaps you are not hitting the problem I'm thinking about. (See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1946854/currentculture-and-currentuiculture-get-reset-to-system-culture-on-ui-event)